# Not able get access token and validation api for microsoft accounts .(Oauth2.0)

Tags: c#, security, outlook, oauth-2.0

Google and facebook have provided API get and validate token like -

https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=

I am not able to find such api microsoft accounts .

I want to get access token in android app for microsoft account  and app will send this token customized service . Service will get back email ID from access token using microsoft oauth api and validate user.

Comment: Me too. I can't find anything anywhere